# Unable to execute all prerequisites for a target in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have been trying to execute all prerequisites for a particular target in makefile. But whenever the prerequisite is a target with single/multiple info values, I find that the other prerequisites are not executed(which come after the 'info' based target)

I have tried reducing the number of info in values in prerequisites to just 1. in that case also i could not find other prerequisites to execute. 
Thus my problem is to understand how to execute a single/multi-line info based prerequisite and continue executing other prerequisites.

```
# Define new line and separator
.PHONY:newline
newline:
    @echo 

.PHONY:separator
separator:
    $(info -------------------------------)

# Print the project details
.PHONY:project
project:
    $(info Project Details)
    $(info Author  : xyz)

# Help menu 
.PHONY:help
help: newline separator project separator newline 



Expected outcome 
$ make help

-------------------------------
Project Details
Author  : xyz
-------------------------------

Outcome received

$ make help

-------------------------------
Project Details
Author  : xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

In make any target's recipe is executed at most once per build. So just don't do this, it's very very wrong.

Also, `$(info ...)` is a text substitution, which is executed before any external command in the same recipe, so mixing it with `echo` generally is a bad idea.

If you're trying to avoid repeating long dash lines, you can always do this with variables:

```
sep := --------------------
define nl :=


endef

...

help:
    $(info $(nl)$(sep))
    $(info Project details)
    ...
    $(info $(sep)$(nl))
```

Comment: Moreover, although GNU `make` does process prerequisites in order when running in serial mode, the `make` specifications don't actually require that, and one should not depend on it.  Where target-building order needs to be managed, that should be done via target / prerequisite relationships.  Among other things, that will ensure an acceptable build order with parallel `make`.